# Write a function that adds parentheses to the beginning and end to make all parentheses match and return it

Tags: c++, string, vector, parentheses

Given a string of parentheses, such as `(((())((()`, write a function that adds parentheses to the beginning and end to make all parentheses match and return it.

I'm trying to figure out how to output this.

Input: `)(()(`

Output: `()(()())`

I've tried using `cout << pMatch()` but does not give me the output desired above.

It has to be the same as above. Any help is much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

string paranFix(string input) {
    string output;
    vector<string> strVector;

    for (unsigned int a = 0; a < input.size(); ++a) {
        if (input[a] == ')') {
            if (strVector.empty()) {
                output += "(";
            }
            else {
                strVector.pop_back();
            }
        }
        else if (input[a] == '(') {
            strVector.push_back(")");
        }
        output += input[a];
    }

    while (!strVector.empty()) {
        output += strVector.back();
        strVector.pop_back();
    }
    return output;
};

int main(){

    string s = "(((())((()"; // Given String

    cout << "INPUT: "; // Need to output --> "INPUT: )(()( "

    cout << "OUTPUT: "; // Need to output --> "OUTPUT: ()(()()) "

    cout << paranFix(s); // This outputs: (((())((())))), which is incorrect

    return 0;
}
```

This is what the compiler should be outputting with the given String of parentheses `(((())((()`.

```
Input: `)(()(`

Output: `()(()())`
```

Comment: Add `n` opening brackets to the left and `n` closing brackets to the right. Then add brackets so that the number of opening and closing ones matches. The result is not shortest, but it's the simplest approach.

Comment: Can you add the actual output you are getting with this code?

Comment: This is an overly complicated attempt at solving a simple problem.  Why not just balance as you go?  I don't see the need for a stack.  https://godbolt.org/z/AG-msz

Comment: @paddy I'm not using stacks, (they're just variable names) and again, I'm trying to figure out how to output what is in the code. BOTH input and output in the main function.

Comment: It may be a vector, but you're _using_ it as a stack.  So I call it a stack.

Comment: @paddy Just modified the code. Should be more clearer now. Also look in main function for clarification.

Comment: Hey @WolfAngleBlade I tried a noob way to solve this with counting the open and close parentheses [Check Here](https://github.com/Ronje0993/HackerRankPractice/blob/master/StackOverflowSolutions/MatchingParentheses.cpp). This is not a perfect solution, But see if it can trigger your imagination further. i did not save the character in stack because it would take some space, rather just kept its count.

Comment: @RC0993 You're close. The input seems good. But remember that the string of parentheses is already given: ”(((())((()”. Also, the output in the program you've shown me is outputting OUTPUT: ()(())(). Should be "OUTPUT: ()(()())".

Comment: Hey @WolfAngleBlade Can you write  _clear combinations_ of **Input-output-expected output**, so that the problem can be handled properly? You can edit your post, giving a set of inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: With your last comment, what I understand is there should not be any alterations in the input string, thus the **input string** would be a **substring** of the **output**...

Comment: @RC0993 It Is Done.

Comment: Guys, I think I figured it out. See answer.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone I think I figured it out! @RC0993 was the first to point this out!

`string s = (((())((();` should be `string s = ")(()("; // which is the INPUT;`

And

```
cout << "INPUT: " << s << endl;

cout << "OUTPUT: " << pMatch(s) << endl;
```

Here what it outputs in respect to `string s = ")(()("; // The Input`

```
INPUT: )(()(
OUTPUT: ()(()())
```

that was just a hardcoded input.

reason i knew that is because i traced its usage

its used here
    `cout << paranFix(s); // This outputs: (((())((()))))` if `string s = (((())((();`

which has the signature `string paranFix(string input);`

thus, `s` becomes local variable input

(finally! a decently named variable!)

Comment: **It's good that you were able to solve it**, but I'm still not sure what was wrong and how did it get solved. Maybe try elaborating your thoughts/problems with more clarity of _what_ you **did**, _what_ you **expected** and _what_ you **got** so that other users here can help ***you*** figure out _what_ went **wrong** clearly...